# is there something wrong in this code?

Tags: python

This is the code I've made to present 2 options instead of 3, so this is just off the top of my head. There might be a lot of mistakes in the code because I just started two days ago. When I run it, the diamonds selection works fine but the gold and the hungry chest get jumbled together.

```
import random
import time
import pygame

def displayIntro():
    print ('You are in a land full of chests. In front of you,')
    print ('you see three caves. In one cave, the chest is full of diamonds.')
    print ('in the second cave, the chest is full of iron')
    print ('the last chest is greedy and hungry, and will eat you on sight.')
    print ()

def chooseCave():
    cave = ''
    while cave  != '1'and cave !='2'and cave != '3':
        print ('Which cave will you go into (1,2 or 3)')
        cave = input()
    return cave

def checkCave(chosenCave):
    print('You approach the cave.....')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('It is dark and spooky....')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('the chest is....')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)

    diamondCave = random.randint(1, 3)
    goldCave = random.randint(1, 3)
    while diamondCave == goldCave:
        goldCave = random.randint(1, 3)

        if chosenCave == str(diamondCave):

        pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
        print('full of diamonds!')

    elif print('full of gold!'):
pass
    else:
        print('hungry and gobbles you down in one bite!')

 playAgain = 'yes'
    while playAgain == 'yes' or playAgain == 'y':

    displayIntro ()

    caveNumber = chooseCave()

    checkCave(caveNumber)

    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    playAgain = input()
else:
        pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("test.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() == True:
    continue
```

Comment: Your indentation doesn't seem to be valid. Please try copy/pasting the code again, taking special care to preserve indentation.

Comment: what is `elif print('full of gold!'):`?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this section, particularly the `elif` case:

```
if chosenCave == str(diamondCave):
    print('full of diamonds!')
elif print('full of gold!'):
    pass
else:
    print('hungry and gobbles you down in one bite!')
```

Here, the `print` is the *condition* of the `elif`, i.e. it executes it, checks its result value, which is `None`, and continues with the `else` case, because the boolean value of `None` is `False`.

Try this instead:

```
if chosenCave == str(diamondCave):
    print('full of diamonds!')
elif chosenCave == str(goldCave):
    print('full of gold!')
else:
    print('hungry and gobbles you down in one bite!')
```